# Flutter GridView count update gives wrong scroll position

Tags: gridview, scroll, dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter and trying to implement the grid list.

I used `GridView` to do this.

I want my `GridView` to show 2 items on each row by default

and when user clicks the button on the `AppBar`,

I want to change the count of my `GridView`

so that it can show only one item per row.

To implement this behavior,

I created `MyApp`, `_GridCountButton`, `MainList`.

`MyApp` is a `StatefulWidget` that holds `_gridCount`.

`_GridCountButton` is a `StatelessWidget` and receives listener from `MyApp` and invokes the listener when it's pressed.

`MainList` is the one that holds `GridView`.

[image: count: 2]
[image: count: 1]

As you can see, change of the grid works,

but the scroll position of the `GridView` is not what I wanted.

It seems like it maintains the absolute value of the scroll.

What can I do to maintain the first item on the screen to be same?

Comment: You may want to use a custom `ScrollController` and then check the `jumpTo` method of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I roughly solved my problem, so this solution may not work in other cases.

**Best Solution Might Be**

The best solution might be using `ScrollController` to listen and move to specific offset calculated with the `height` of the items.

To get the `height` of the item, I found a way to do this in `initState()` callback, but I made my List `StatelessWidget` so it doesn't have `initState()`.

### What I did

**My case**

So I just used the ratio of the size of the items to get the proper offset.

In my case, I had to show 1 or 2 items per row, `grid1` and `grid2` respectively.

So I stored the offset of `grid1` and `grid2` to `offset` and `offset2`.

Then the relation between `offset1` and `offset2` will be `offset1 = offset2*4`, since `grid1` can show only 1 item when `grid2` can show 4 items with the same space.

**Why not just `offset`?**

I tried using just one `offset` variable storing the offset of `grid1`.

When scroll event is called, I calculated `offset` to always hold the offset of `grid1`.

However, scroll event doesn't get called when there are no scrolls.

So when I

1. toggle from `grid1` to `grid2`,
2. don't do any scroll,
3. toggle from `grid2` to `grid1`,

the value of `offset` remains the same, and is recognized as the offset of `grid2`.

So I separated `offset1` and `offset2` to make sure what offset matches what grid.

**With `offset1` and `offset2`**

Now that I have the right values that updates properly, I can now set this value to set the proper offset.

When I call `setState` to toggle the grid, I added following lines.

```
setState(() {
  double offset = 0.0; // offset to be set
  if(_gridCount == 2) {
    _gridCount = 1;
    offset = offset1; // set offset1
  } else {
    _gridCount = 2;
    offset = offset2; // set offset2
  }
  _scrollController.jumpTo(offset); // set proper offset
});
```

And it worked!

Comment: Glad you've accomplished.

Comment: @miguelpruivo Thanks to you giving me direction!

Answer (score 0):

Please check my attempt to this problem. The gridview changes from the double grid to single and vice versa when tapped on the item. Any suggestion or changes is welcomed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter TabBar',
      home: new Home(),
      theme: new ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.black),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  double _offset;
  double _doubleGridItemHeight = 100.0;
  double _singleGridItemHeight = 200.0;
  int _gridCount = 2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        print("offset = ${_scrollController.offset}");
        setState(() {
          _offset = _scrollController.offset;
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 40,
        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: _gridCount),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              height: _gridCount == 1
                  ? _doubleGridItemHeight
                  : _singleGridItemHeight,
              child: new Card(
                elevation: 5.0,
                child: new Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: new Text('Item $index'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_gridCount == 2) {
                  _gridCount = 1;
                  // scrolling with animation
                  _scrollController.animateTo(
                      _offset +
                          ((index) *
                              (_doubleGridItemHeight + _singleGridItemHeight)),
                      curve: Curves.linear,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
                } else {
                  _gridCount = 2;
                  // scrolling without animation
                  _scrollController.jumpTo(_offset -
                      ((index) *
                          (_doubleGridItemHeight + _singleGridItemHeight)));
                }
              });
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```